# WooCommerce get product attribute taxonomy value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am able to successfully pull and update post meta as expected using the following.

```
function update_post_type_post_prodd(  $post_id ) {

$personalization = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_qty_discount_code', true );

if ($personalization === 'R'){

$gfdata ='a:28:{s:2:"id";}';
   
    $emptyRemoved = unserialize($gfdata);

    update_post_meta( $post_id,'_gravity_form_data', $emptyRemoved );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'update_post_type_post_prodd' );
```

Pull meta field `_qty_discount_code`

and if it contains the value `R`

update the meta field `_gravity_form_data` with `$gfdata` on post save.

**However**, when attempting to pull a product attribute taxonomy `pa_personalization` I get crickets.

I have tried multiple methods to no avail. Does this looks correct?

```
function update_post_type_post_prodd(  $post_id ) {

//$personalization = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'pa_personalization', true );

$taxonomy = 'pa_personalization';
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
$term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);
$personalization = $term->name;

if ($personalization === 'yes'){

$emptyRemoved = unserialize($gfdata);

    update_post_meta( $post_id,'_gravity_form_data', $emptyRemoved );
}
}
//execute the function whenever post type is being updated
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'update_post_type_post_prodd' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'update_post_type_post_prodd', 10, 3);

function update_post_type_post_prodd($post_id, $post, $update) {

    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    $pa_personalization = $product->get_attribute('pa_personalization');
    $attributes_values = explode(',', $pa_personalization);

    if (in_array('yes', $attributes_values)) {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

The hook `do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update )` receives 3 parameter.

Comment: Boom! That worked only caveat for others to watch out for, it was case sensitive in my instance `Yes` vs `yes` made a difference. Thank you for solving this.