# Check the Woocommerce Product Attribute on Archive Page and do something

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product, taxonomy

On my Woocommerce site, I have 2 different product attributes (artist and type). I want to execute some code when on a **attribute archive page** containing one of those attributes and their value. For example:

on site.com/artist/rembrandt/ showing all products made by Rembrandt (pa_rembrandt), I want to add the text "please see all painings by Rembrandt" etc. This is what I tried so fare:

```
<?php add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'artist_description' ); 
function artist_description() { 
if (is_product_taxonomy() && is_tax(pa_artist)) {

echo "Please see all paintings made by";
echo is_tax(pa_artist));
echo ".";
}
} ?>
```

But that clearly is not working. When I remove the `&& is_tax(pa_artist)` the code does show the text "Please see all paintings made by." but without the actual painter and turns up on every archive page. Who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333424/check-if-page-is-a-woocommerce-attribute

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by using (and stripping) the title and changing the code to this:

```
function artist_description() { 
if (is_product_taxonomy() & is_tax('pa_artist')) {

echo "All paintings made by " ;
$artist = sprintf(__('%1$s'), single_term_title('', false));
    echo $artist;
    echo ". </br>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'artist_description');

function artist_description() {
    if (check_is_wc_attribute('Artist')) {

        echo "Please see all paintings made by";
    }
}

function check_is_wc_attribute($attribute_name) {

    /**
     * Attributes are proper taxonomies, therefore first thing is 
     * to check if we are on a taxonomy page using the is_tax(). 
     * Also, a further check if the taxonomy_is_product_attribute 
     * function exists is necessary, in order to ensure that this 
     * function does not produce fatal errors when the WooCommerce 
     * is not  activated
     */
    if (is_tax() && function_exists('taxonomy_is_product_attribute')) {

        return taxonomy_is_product_attribute($attribute_name);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This kind of works, but does not echo the Artist value after the Please see all paintings made by".

Comment: Check this for attribute values- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71981492/1117368

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below. It will add the text on every archive page/ listing page in products grid after product title. This text will show on specific products in which you have added this attribute.

```
function artist_description() {
    global $product;
    $artist_val = $product->get_attribute('pa_artist');
    if ($artist_val) {
        echo "Please see all paintings made by ";
        echo $artist_val;
        echo ".";
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'artist_description' );
```

Comment: This echo's the value below every product, instead I want it on top of the page.